# average column content based on range from another file

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

I have two files: .bedGraph and .bed. the .bedGraph contains cooordinates + intensity value (chr, start, end, intensity) while the .bed file has only coordinates (chr, start, end).

the bed file is made by pulling together coordinates that are at max 1000bp far away. this reduced the ~66 million reads from the bedGraph to ~300k.

so, my bedGraph look like this

```
chr1    10037   10038   0.413963 
chr1    10393   10428   0.827926 
chr1    10540   10546   0.413963 
chr1    10610   10615   0.413963 
chr1    11281   11282   0.413963
```

and my bed looks like this

```
chr1    10037   56175
chr1    57265   58983
chr1    60022   64415
chr1    65485   74471
chr1    76305   177390
chr1    227433  267689
chr1    317665  384576
chr1    386108  417753
chr1    420243  423692
chr1    425613  426755
```

so what I want to do now is to add a column on the bed graph that has the average intensity of the reads (taken from the .bedGraph file) that falls within that region, i.e.

```
.bedGraph
chr   1   10   1.23413    |
chr   11  18   0.234      | this <<----------
chr   20  24   4.231      |                 |
chr   57  100  2.123413   |                 |
chr   101 123  2.333                        |
                                            |
            I want to add this              | 
                |                           |
                |                           |
                V                           |
.bed                                        |
chr   1   100  (average of ------------------
chr   110 400  (same as above for another interval)
```

so...I wrote a script so far and the idea is that I get the coordinates of the .bed file, then store all the intensity values in the bedGraph file that correspond to the data within that interval and then print out the original bed + the averaged intensity value...easy so far...
here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(sum);

############################
## call with
## perl average_intensities.pl IN1.bed IN2.bedGraph > OUT.bedGraph
############################

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;

if (not defined $file1) {
    die "Need name INPUT 1 file (bed)\n";
}

if (not defined $file2) {
    die "Need name INPUT 2 file (bedGraph)\n";
}

#declare stuff for first file
my @coords1;
my $chr1;
my $start1;
my $end1;

my @coords2;
my $chr2;
my $start2;
my $end2;
my $int;
my @intensity;
my $av_int;

print "about to open files\n"; ## <<-- this doesn't even print :(

open (IN1, '<', $file1) or die "Could not open $file1: $! \n";
open (IN2, '<' ,$file2) or die "Could not open $file2: $! \n";

#parse first file and get teh first coordinates
while(<IN1>){
    chomp $_;

    @coords1 = split "\t", $_;
    $chr1 = $coords1[0];
    $start1 = $coords1[1];
    $end1 = $coords1[2];

    #parse second file and get the coordinates + intensities
    while(<IN2>){
        chomp $_;
        @coords2 = split "\t", $_;
        $chr2 = $coords2[0];
        $start2 = $coords2[1];
        $end2 = $coords2[2];
        $int = $coords2[3];
        if ($chr1 eq $chr2){

            # if the coordinates on bedGraph are still < than those on bed save the average intensity
            if($start1 <= $end2){
                push @intensity, $int;
            } else {
                if (scalar @intensity >0){
                    $av_int = sum(@intensity)/(scalar @intensity);
                    print join ("\t", $chr1, $start1, $start2, $av_int),"\n";
                    @intensity = ();
                    last;
                }
            }
        } else {
            next;
        }
    }
}
close(IN1);
close(IN2);
```

however, when I try to run it, it tells me

```
Use of uninitialized value $start2 in numeric le (<=) at average_intensities.pl line 49, <IN2> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $start1 in numeric le (<=) at average_intensities.pl line 49, <IN2> line 1.
```

(...and it goes on for all the lines in the file) and I can't understand why since I did declare both variables.
I'm not sure at this point what's wrong with the code that causes it...
any suggestion would be great!
thanks :)

###########################################

UPDATED CODE BELOW
I corrected the code as suggested by Kenosis and I slightly modified his script:

```
open IN1, "$file1" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
open IN2, "$file2" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";

my %bedGraphHoA;


while (<IN1>) {
    my @cols = split;
    push @{ $bedGraphHoA{ $cols[0] } }, [ @cols[ 1 .. 3 ] ];
}

close IN1;

while (<IN2>) {
    my ( @bedGaphLines, @bedGaphVals );
    my @cols = split;
    if ( exists $bedGraphHoA{ $cols[0] } ) {

        for my $elements ( @{ $bedGraphHoA{ $cols[0] } } ) {

            if ( $elements->[0] >= $cols[1] and $elements->[1] <= $cols[2] ) {
                push @bedGaphLines, $elements;
                push @bedGaphVals,  $elements->[2];
            }
        }
        if (scalar @bedGaphVals > 0){
            my $mean = ( sum @bedGaphVals ) / @bedGaphVals;
            print join( "\t", $cols[0],$cols[1], $cols[2], $mean ), "\n";
        }

    }
}

close IN2;
```

I tested it on a subset of the real data and looks like it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
@coords1 = split $line1, "\t";
```

when what you meant was:

```
@coords1 = split "\t", $line1;
```

And the same later, where you have:

```
@coords2 = split $line2, "\t";
```

you meant:

```
@coords2 = split "\t", $line2;
```

Both `$start1` and `$start2` take their values from the results of the `split`s, in `@coords1` and `@coords2`, respectively.

Perhaps the following will provide some direction for your effort:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/sum/;

my %bedGraphHoA;

open my $bedGraphFH, '<', 'bedGraph.txt' or die $!;

while (<$bedGraphFH>) {
    my @cols = split;
    push @{ $bedGraphHoA{ $cols[0] } }, [ @cols[ 1 .. 3 ] ];
}

close $bedGraphFH;

open my $bedFH, '<', 'bed.txt' or die $!;

while (<$bedFH>) {
    my ( @bedGaphLines, @bedGaphVals );
    my @cols = split;
    if ( exists $bedGraphHoA{ $cols[0] } ) {
        for my $elements ( @{ $bedGraphHoA{ $cols[0] } } ) {
            if ( $elements->[0] >= $cols[1] and $elements->[1] <= $cols[2] ) {
                push @bedGaphLines, $elements;
                push @bedGaphVals,  $elements->[2];
            }
        }

    }
    my $mean = ( sum @bedGaphVals ) / @bedGaphVals;
        print join( "\t", $cols[0], @{ $bedGaphLines[$_] }, $mean ), "\n"
          for 0 .. $#bedGaphLines;
}

close $bedFH;

__END__

bedGraph.txt:
chr   1   10   1.23413
chr   11  18   0.234
chr   20  24   4.231
chr   57  100  2.123413
chr   101 123  2.333
chr   120 123  7.555
chr   150 200  1.275

bed.txt:
chr   1   100
chr   110 400

Output:
chr 1   10  1.23413 1.95563575
chr 11  18  0.234   1.95563575
chr 20  24  4.231   1.95563575
chr 57  100 2.123413    1.95563575
chr 120 123 7.555   4.415
chr 150 200 1.275   4.415
```

Comment: auch...I should have seen that..!! I corrected the code (see above) but now I get into the problem that I have no output :-/!! I would expect to see the same number of rows of my .bed file but I see none...any idea? I'll also write it in the main post! thanks :)

Comment: @Seb - I've provided some code which may be helpful.

Comment: yes, I did change that part of code and edited my question (I used $_ instead of $line), however, it does not print successfully yet...

Comment: @Seb - Sorry--thought I updated my edit.  You should now see the code I mentioned earlier.

Comment: thanks for the code! I see that you used hashes to store the data (i think my problem is that I try to do everything with arrays :-/) and I'll look that up asap (I'm finishing off a midterm now). at first sight I think I will modify it to have the average output with the `bed.txt` tho.

Comment: you can see in the post up how I modified it. now it works printing out the averages based on the intervals in the bed file :)